# Is it possible to combine an EditTextPreference with a CheckBoxPreference?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a PreferenceActivity with, among other things, a category including call forward options. What I want is a preference that:

- Enables/Disables if the user presses a checkbox on the right.
- Opens up the EditTextPreference dialog if the user presses the text(or anything else in the preference)

It's probably not of any use but here is a snippet of this particular preferencecategory :

```
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/category_callforward">

    <EditTextPreference
            android:key="call_forward_always"
            android:title="@string/call_forward_always"
            android:summary="@string/call_forward_forwardto" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

**EDIT**

*I'd like to implement it in this method if possible:*

```
    // Locates the correct data from saved preferences and sets input type to numerics only
private void setCallForwardType()
{
    ep1 = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("call_forward_always");

    EditText et = (EditText) ep1.getEditText();
    et.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());

}
```

**EDIT2**

*If anyone is still wondering - this is what I want as a Preference:*

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GHOeK.png]

**EDIT3**

*I've searched around for a couple hours now and have come up with a single word: 'PreferenceGroupAdapter'. I have not, however, been able to find examples or tutorials showing me how to use it. Suggestions ? Is this even the correct path to go?*

**EDIT4**

*If this really isn't possibly I would very much like a suggestion to an alternative(user-friendly) solution that I can implement instead of the combined Edit- and Checkbox preference.*

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this problem? I've been looking at trying to create a custom preference like this, either with the checkbox on the preference row, or incorporated into the preference dialog, but this is the only reference I've managed to find anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. First, create a class for preferences which should be extended from `PreferenceActivity`. Use like this:

```
// editbox ise your EditTextPreference, so set it.  
checkbox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_preference");

checkbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if(newValue.toString().equals("false")) {
            PrefActivity.this.editbox.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
            PrefActivity.this.editbox.setEnabled(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I already have my SettingsActivity which, obviously, extends PreferenceActivity. Can't I simply create a method within this class that follows your suggestion ?
Also. you're using findPreference(). Should these chechboxpreferences be added programatically in onCreate() ?

Comment: Yes, create a method named `listeners` and call in `onCreate` method. It will work.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can define in `onCreate` or in new method. Also not forget `EditTextPreference`.

Comment: See my edit. So should I create an array of checkboxpreferences in here, then implement your suggestion here? (setCallForwardType() is called in onCreate)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I think I've managed to create something similar with a dialog that creates a layout with an edit text and a checkbox, it should be possible to do the same in a normal layout:

```
 public class CheckEditTextPreference extends DialogPreference {
    private static final String KEY_PROPERTY_DISABLED = "key_property_disabled";
    private EditText editText;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private String text;
    private boolean isDisabled;
    private SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    public CheckEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        return buildUi();
    }

    /**
     * Build a dialog using an EditText and a CheckBox
     */
    private View buildUi() {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(25, 0, 0, 0);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        checkBox = new CheckBox(getContext());
        editText = new EditText(getContext());

        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        checkBox.setText("Disabled");

        FrameLayout dialogView = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        linearLayout.addView(editText);
        linearLayout.addView(checkBox);
        dialogView.addView(linearLayout);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                editText.setEnabled(!isChecked);
            }
        });

        return dialogView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        checkBox.setChecked(isDisabled());
        editText.setText(getText());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
            if (callChangeListener(text)) {
                setText(text);
            }

            if (callChangeListener(isChecked)) {
                isDisabled(isChecked);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getString(index);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
        setText(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedString("") : defaultValue.toString());
        isDisabled(mySharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_PROPERTY_DISABLED, true));
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        this.text = value;
        persistString(this.text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    private void isDisabled(boolean value) {
        this.isDisabled = value;
        mySharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_PROPERTY_DISABLED, this.isDisabled).apply();
    }

    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return this.isDisabled;
    }
}
```

And put this into your preferences screen:

```
    <your.package.name.CheckEditTextPreference
        android:key="chkEtPref"
        android:title="Title"/>
```

[image: Disabled]
[image: Enabled]

Answer (score 1):

Define a key in `res/values/strings.xml` for your `CheckBoxPreference`.

Give your `CheckBoxPreference` the XML attribute `android:key="@string/THE_KEY_YOU_DEFINED"` so that it will automatically save state in `SharedPreferences`.

Give your `EditTextPreference` the XML attribute `android:dependency="@string/THE_KEY_YOU_DEFINED`.

The `EditTextPreference` should then enable / disable depending on the state of the `CheckBoxPreference`.